# Does .NET MAUI have an adjustable split view feature?

Tags: maui

I'm evaluating .NET MAUI for an upcoming project, but one thing I see missing that I need is a splitter feature. I get that a splitter may not make sense on mobile, but I'm mainly targeting Windows Desktop, MAC OS and iPAD anyway.

Has anyone seen anything that would provide an adjustable split view on MAUI?

Answer (score 0):

> Does .NET MAUI have an adjustable split view feature?

Yes, you can refer to this doc: [.NET MAUI TwoPaneView layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/twopaneview). It said:

> The TwoPaneView class represents a container with two views that size and position content in the available space, either side-by-side or top-to-bottom. TwoPaneView inherits from Grid so the easiest way to think about these properties is as if they are being applied to a grid.

You can follow the doc to achieve it. In addition, it also provide the sample: [TwoPaneView](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/TwoPaneView).

Wish it can help you.

Comment: I tried this already. Unfortunately on desktop, I couldn't see a way for the user to do a click and drag to resize the panes like a traditional split view.

Answer (score 0):

The recent .NET 8 update has now made it possible to create your own splitter. The following class will resize the column to the left of the splitter on the DragOver event.

Place the splitter in your grid between two columns:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yournamespace.Controls"

<local:SplitterControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="splitter"/>
```

SplitterControl ContentView

Add the SplitterControl.xaml.cs to your project:

```
namespace STIGstatements.Resources.Controls;

public partial class SplitterControl : ContentView
{

    public SplitterControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupGestureRecognizers();
    }

    private void SetupGestureRecognizers()
    {
        var dragGestureRecognizer = new DragGestureRecognizer();
        dragGestureRecognizer.DragStarting += OnDragStarting;
        splitter.GestureRecognizers.Add(dragGestureRecognizer);

        // Setup DropGestureRecognizer when the control is added to the grid
        PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Parent" && this.Parent is Grid parentGrid)
            {
                var dropGestureRecognizer = new DropGestureRecognizer();
                dropGestureRecognizer.DragOver += OnDragOver;
                parentGrid.GestureRecognizers.Add(dropGestureRecognizer);
            }
        };
    }

    private void OnDragStarting(object sender, DragStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        splitter.IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void OnDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateSplitterPosition(sender, e);
    }

    public void UpdateSplitterPosition(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        int columnIndex = Grid.GetColumn(this);
        columnIndex--;

        var newWidth = (int)e.GetPosition(null)!.Value.X;

        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.WinUI)
        {
            e.PlatformArgs.DragEventArgs.DragUIOverride!.IsCaptionVisible = false;
            e.PlatformArgs.DragEventArgs.DragUIOverride!.IsGlyphVisible = false;
        }

        splitter.IsVisible = true;

        var parentGrid = Parent as Grid;

        if (parentGrid != null && columnIndex < parentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count)
        {
            parentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[columnIndex].Width = new GridLength(newWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

And SplitterControl.XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="STIGstatements.Resources.Controls.SplitterControl">
    <BoxView x:Name="splitter"
             WidthRequest="5"
             Color="#757474"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
            <DragGestureRecognizer DragStarting="OnDragStarting" />
        </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
    </BoxView>
</ContentView>
```